# What is the norm of matrices? Is it related to the norms of linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

What are the norms of a matrix? Is there any relation with norm of linear operators/transformations?

Comment: You could just google that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible norms for a matrix:

- the usual norms as an element of  the vector space $K^{n^2}$ $\;(K=\mathbf R\;$ or $\;\mathbf C)$. Among these, the `2-norm` is called the `Frobenius norm`. It is also equal to $\;\sqrt{\operatorname{Tr}(A^*A)}$.
- matrix norms, which are $K$-algebra norms, i.e. sub-multiplicative norms. The Frobenius norm is a matrix norm.
- the *operator norm* (also named *Hilbert-Schmidt norm*):
  $$\lVert A\rVert=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{\lVert Ax\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert\le 1}\frac{\lVert Ax\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}=\sup_{\lVert x\rVert=1}\frac{\lVert Ax\rVert}{\lVert x\rVert}.$$

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different norms that are used for matrices, depending on the context. You can find a list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), or if you provide the context I can explain what's usually used there.

Comment: @b-r-datt Please note that the mentioned list is non-exhaustive, though, as there are infinitely many matrix norms.